# simple javascript help

Tags: javascript

hi im new to javascript and basically trying to work out.
when i click on the links to display an image in a place holder.
if placeholder1 is used by either 1.jpg, 2.jpg, or 3.jpg then to leave placeholder1 with that image and use placeholder2.
hope that makes sense
thanks for any help

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function showPic (whichpic) { 
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById('placeholder1').src = whichpic.href
        if (whichpic.title) { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true; 
    } 
}
</script>

<div style="border: 1px solid #999; padding: 1em; margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
<ul>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="/images/1.jpg" title="A bunch of bananas on a table">some bananas</a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="/images/2.jpg" title="Condiments in a Chinese restaurant">two bottles</a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="/images/3.jpg" title="Seashells on a table">some shells</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="desc">Choose an image to begin</p>
<img id="placeholder1" src="/images/blank.gif" alt="" />
<img id="placeholder2" src="/images/blank.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to find out what the value of an attribute in an element is, you can use jQuery like so ....

```
var src = $('#placeholder1').attr('src');
```

you can then use index of, or some other string function to determine if the src attribute contrains the filename you're interested in.

Comment: yeah.... include a 50kB library just for `$('#placeholder1').attr('src')` instead of `document.getElementById('placeholde1').src`

Comment: and all the other benefits it offers, but hey you're entitled to your opinion/preferences :) Maybe the Lee doesn't know about jQuery, so I've just introduced him to something that will make his life easier :D

Comment: thanks Anthony i've read a bit about jQuery just never used it :/ im trying all 3 answers and will see which i get working first :)

Comment: @Lee I've only scratched the surface of it, but it's really powerful. But if you're not going to use it that much then maybe it'd be better to write your own specific set of utility functions to help you with your site.

Comment: Maybe. I'm new to coding :) only started learned php and my sql around 2 months. is a steep learning curve for me. starting to get confused with different syntax's of different languages now :(

Comment: once you get the basic understanding then it's all just syntax eventually :) have fun!

Comment: Strongly believe that first you have to learn the language... than the framework...

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I don't know enough about the "getAttribute" method to address it's cross browser compatibility...

```
function showPic (whichpic) { 
    if (document.getElementById) {
        if(document.getElementById('placeholder1').getAttribute("src") == "/images/blank.gif") {
           document.getElementById('placeholder1').src = whichpic.href;
        } else {
           document.getElementById('placeholder2').src = whichpic.href;
        }
        if (whichpic.title) { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true; 
    } 
}
```

Edit: switched '.src' to 'getAttribute("src")'

Comment: thanks, this looks like what i want but for some reason is not going to placeholder2 when i click for another image to be shown.

Comment: It looks like I overlooked the fact that READING from the .src attribute will return the full path to the file. So "http: //www.foo.com/path/to/image.jpg" rather than "/path/to/image.jpg".  To fix this use: .getAttribute("src") instead of just .src.  Edited above to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to placeholder1 in a variable.  Check the src of placeholder1 to see if it is any of the images you mentioned (In my example, I use a regular expression to accomplish that).  If it is one of those images, reassign your variable to a reference to placeholder2:

```
function showPic (whichpic) { 
    var ph = document.getElementById('placeholder1');
    if (/[1-3]\.jpg/.test(ph.src)) {
        ph = document.getElementById('placeholder2');
    }
    ph.src = whichpic.href;
    var descChild = document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0];
    descChild.nodeValue = whichpic.title || whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Note, you don't need to test for the existence of `document.getElementById`.  If the browser supports JavaScript, it supports `document.getElementById`.